# Please help me identify this Android party-based turn-based dungeon-crawler

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I have played an Android game some time in the past, on one of the phones I previously used that no longer works now, and I want to play this game again.

If I remember correctly, I played this game in 2019 or 2020, the game's language is English; the game is rendered in top-down perspective, more specifically it is rendered as if you are viewing the map from directly above, the center line of your vision strikes the center of the map vertically, and the view isn't tilted.

The camera of the game, using definitions from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#/media/File:Graphical_projection_comparison.png), would be best described as plan projection (first cell from right in the top row in the picture), but a  plan 3D perspective projection instead of 2D orthographic projection.

The art style of the game is like those found in western animations (realistic artistic 3D American comic-book style rendering, if these words make sense together), IIRC. And the game is turn-based, and, character movement is restricted to a hexagon grid IIRC.

The characters are physically proportional, without big heads and short legs and the like.

The game world is definitely in a fantasy setting, evidently inspired by Dungeons & Dragons and the works of Tolkien;

The game is a party-based dungeon-crawler, players select six characters IIRC, and progress through levels of dungeons.

The above are all I can recall about the game, I am sorry if there is not enough information to help identify the game, but the game's camera makes it distinct among Android games, anyway I can't find it on Google Play, what is this game?

Note. It's not:

- Hoplite
- Hexagon Dungeon

---

To give more information, the camera of the game works like this:

Heroes of Steel:
[image: screenshot of a top down tile based computer game]

But it is 3D and the characters are more realistic (because they are in 3D).

And the game play is more like this:

Demon's Rise 2:
[image: screenshot of an isometric computer game with hex-tiles.]

But it's like you are viewing the game-world directly from the above, not as if you are viewing something in front of you and below you.

The art style is somewhere between the two, if the first is more artistic and the second is realistic, the game's art style is realistically artistic.

Comment: Unfortunately both of the above aren't correct.

Comment: [Cardinal Quest 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kongregate.mobile.cardinalquest.google&hl=en&gl=US)?

Comment: [Final Fantasy Pixel Remaster](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cLR1XzooW1M)?

Comment: Also wrong, the game is played in a hexagon grid and is using perspective projection from above.